# xslt conditional sum of grandparent

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I have a simple `for-each` shown below. Essentially what I'm trying to do is get all `studentResults` with a certain `studentID`. This part appears to work as intended.

The `if` statement checks if the sum of `result` is greater than `59`. This parts also works as intended.

Now to what's not working. Once this condition is met (sum is greater than 59) it should then go two parents up and then sum the value in that node. As shown in the XML tree.

**XSLT**

```
        <xsl:for-each select="//studentResult[@studentID=$sid]">
          <xsl:if test="sum(result) &gt; 59">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(../../creditPoints)"/>
          </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
```

**XML**

```
<root>
  <units>
    <unit>
      <title>Accounting I</title>
      <creditPoints>20</creditPoints>

      <studentResults>
        <studentResult studentID="#1092">
          <result>30</result>
          <result>10</result>
          <result>40</result>
        </studentResult>

        <studentResult studentID="#1800">
          <result>30</result>
          <result>10</result>
          <result>8</result>
        </studentResult>
      </studentResults>

    </unit>

    <unit>
      <title>Economics II</title>
      <creditPoints>25</creditPoints>

      <studentResults>
        <studentResult studentID="#1092">
          <result>20</result>
          <result>10</result>
          <result>35</result>
        </studentResult>

        <studentResult studentID="#2500">
          <result>25</result>
          <result>5</result>
          <result>40</result>
        </studentResult>
      </studentResults>

    </unit>
  </units>
</root>
```

---

The following alternate XSLT idea came to mind before submitting the question.

**Alternate XSLT** : 
This prints the total of ALL `creditPoints` even if the student is not in that unit.

```
      <xsl:for-each select="/root/units/unit/studentResults/studentResult[@studentID=$sid][sum(result) &gt; 59]">
            <xsl:value-of select="sum(ancestor::units/unit/creditPoints)"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
```

**Note that this is XSLT 1.0.**

Comment: Please explain what "Now to what's not working" means, show us the result you want and the one you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps simply replacing the whole `for-each` with

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(/root/units/unit[studentResult/studentResult[@studentID = $sid][sum(result) > 59]]/creditPoints)"/>
```

is all you want.

Comment: Posted as I was editing the question. Awesome, I thought it would be much simpler! Also why is it &lt; and not &gt; where does the inversion happen? Also it seems to be ignoring the &lt; 59 condition. But this has got me on the right track, Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, the operator change was simply a mistake on my part.

Comment: No worries, it's perfect. Thank You.